# Перемещение массивов многомерного массива

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, можно сказать наставьте на путь. Есть массив вида:

```
    return array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Главная',
        'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/',

    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Блог',
        'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/blog/',
    ),
 )
```

Как к примеру организовать перемещение массивов `arr[0]` и `arr[1]` вниз и вверх.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
```

переставит вниз. А чтобы переставить вверх, соответственно:

```
array_unshift($arr, array_pop($arr));
```